# The use of 'such' with uncountable nouns

Tags: grammar

Can *such* be used in the following sentence?

> The ball came at such speed that ...

I'd never phrase it like that. More to the point, I am in doubt as to whether *such* can be used with an uncountable noun in that sort of construction. Speed can be considered countable or at least measurable (e.g. *at the speed of 100kph*).

To sum it up, is the sentence in question correct in all circumstances?

Comment: I read it as having a hidden implied word subsequent to the word "such", (example: "The ball came at such *a great* speed that...")

Comment: Used in this way, "such" simply adds emphasis, like "You're such an idiot" or "That was such a good film".  As @Othya says, "such speed" is a contraction of "such a great speed".

Comment: I don't think it has to be great speed, it just has to be somehow defined speed, even if it was slow.

Comment: @Helmar of course... "great" was merely an example.

Comment: The most useful definition of a count noun usage is probably one where numerals may be inserted. Here, 'speed' is non-count (*The balls came at two such speeds that), but count usages are possible (The trains were travelling at two very different speeds).

Comment: _So  `Adj`_ and _such `NP`_ are both used in construction with a _that_-clause describing the result for comparison purposes: _so tired (that) he slept 12 hours; such (a) noise (that) the neighbors woke._ Articles are only required with count nouns, and _noise_, like _speed,_ can be either mass or count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it can.

[Oxford Dictionary Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such):

> Such 3 DETERMINER To so high a degree; so great (often used to emphasize a quality):
>
> this material is of **such importance that** it has a powerful bearing on the case

You could easily take their example sentence and change importance with speed.

> This car drives at **such speed that** using seat belts is advisable.

Or your own:

> The ball came at **such speed that** evading it was impossible and the only option was catching it with the face.

Comment: 'Such' can also be a demonstrative determiner: '... .  Such speeds are dangerous.'